# How to to find the sol. By pascal's roule and mathematical induction

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l}
\text { - For } n \geqslant 2 \text { , prove that } \\
\left(\begin{array}{c}
2 \\
2
\end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{c}
3 \\
2
\end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{c}
4 \\
2
\end{array}\right)+\ldots+\left(\begin{array}{c}
n \\
2
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
n+1 \\
3
\end{array}\right)
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I used Pascal's rule and I didn't get it

Comment: I used mathematical induction and Pascal's rule to prove it at n+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By induction, since the case $n=2$ is straightforward, we have using Pascal's rule
$$ \sum_{p=2}^{n+1}\binom{p}{2}=\sum_{p=2}^n\binom{p}{2}+\binom{n+1}{2}=\binom{n+1}{3}+\binom{n+1}{2}=\binom{n+2}{3} $$
Another way to obtain this result is by simply using Pascal's rule
$$ \binom{p}{k}=\binom{p+1}{k+1}-\binom{p}{k+1} $$ therefore, your sum is equal to
$$ \sum_{p=2}^n\left[\binom{p+1}{3}-\binom{p}{3}\right]=\binom{n+1}{3}-\binom{2}{3}=\binom{n+1}{3} $$
since the terms cancel each other.

Answer (score 0):

Generalizing Tuvasbien's answer,
since
$\binom{p}{k}
=\binom{p+1}{k+1}-\binom{p}{k+1}
$,
if $k \ge 2$,

$\sum_{p=2}^n\binom{p}{k}
=\sum_{p=2}^n\left(\binom{p+1}{k+1}-\binom{p}{k+1}\right)
=\binom{n+1}{k+1}-\binom{2}{k+1}
=\binom{n+1}{k+1}
$.

Your result is $k = 2$.